# JSONArray json_file cant be resolved in while cycle

Tags: java, arrays, json

i coding simple app using json, but have problem with error that json_file cant be resolved
when i put

```
    try {
    JSONArray json_file = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Milanko\\workspace\\primary.json"));
    } catch ...
```

to while cycle it work and no error, but when i have it like this it doesnt work
Anyone any idea ?
Thanks

```
public class ReceivePack extends Thread {

private static DatagramSocket socket;

public void run() {

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {

    JSONArray json_file = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Milanko\\workspace\\primary.json"));

    } catch ...

    while (true) {
        try {
            ...doing with packet

...when i put the code here it works

                JSONObject list1 = new JSONObject();
                list1.put("name", "Milanko");
                json_file.add(list1);       

            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            socket.close();
        }
    }
}
public void kill() {
isRunning = false;
}
}
```

Comment: which json library, which version of it, what's in the loaded jsonfile.

Comment: HI, its json-simple-1.1.1
and json_file.json contain empty array
     [
     ]